# How can I select a video to play from a dropdownlist at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code of aspx page.

```
<object id="obj" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
                     codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"> <param
 name="Filename" **value="video/yaarian.wmv"**> <param name="AutoStart"
 value="true"> <param name="ShowControls" value="true"> <param
 name="BufferingTime" value="2"> <param name="ShowStatusBar"
 value="true"> <param name="AutoSize" value="true"> <param
 name="InvokeURLs" value="false"> <embed id="emb"
 **src="video/yaarian.wmv"** type="application/x-mplayer2" autostart="1" enabled="1"  showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1"
 showcontrols="1"
 pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
 CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0"
 width="480" height="360"></embed> </object>
```

In the code I entered a static path but my requirement is that I want to select a video name from the database, then that video will play. How can I do this?

My .cs file code is

```
String s = videolist.SelectedItem.Value; String s1 = "", s2 = "";
//select path of video
db.con.Open();
try
{
    string str = "select * from video";
    db.com = new SqlCommand(str, db.con);
    SqlDataReader dr = db.com.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (s.Equals(dr["Name"].ToString()))
        {
            s1 = dr["path"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

I want to pass "s1" in place of src attribute of embed tag and value attribute of param tag. How can I do this?

Comment: Very interesting, you are not use the `Where` on SQL statment, but you search all your records one by one, and not only that, even if you find it you continue the loop....

Comment: i am using database class db is an object of that class

Comment: Google it "Sql statement" and read the first result.

Comment: while loop will check the whole table but match the selected vaue

Comment: when s will match any row which is in "Name" column then that row path will be read in s1

Comment: loop will continue but extract only one record

Comment: this cs code is correct i am facing problem in aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Flag the "object" and "embed" tags with runat="server", in this way you can access these items Attribute's collection:

```
obj.Attributes["value"] = s1;
emb.Attributes["src"] = s1;
```

Comment: After you add the runatserver in The .aspx file the two lines of code can be added just below s1=...

Comment: <object id="obj"  runatserver="true" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
                    codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"> in aspx

Comment: in cs file obj.Attributes["value"] = s1;

Comment: Correct, add it also to the embed tag

Comment: but it creates an error obj does not exist in current contex

Comment: Doble check the runatserver flag, whenever you flag a tag with runatserver it will be available to the codebehind, so no error must pop.

Comment: Did you saved the aspx and recompiled?

Comment: what are you saying i couldn't understand. plz explain it

Comment: yes i have saved and try to compile but it generates error

Comment: now what i have to do? plz tell me its my semester project which i have to submit tomorrow but it generates an error

Comment: Here, look at this video, hope it helps you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebUFiGF9tu4

Comment: ok, I must say SORRY!!, that's what happens when you write code without vs XD, the tag is runat="server" not runatserver="true", that's why it says obj does not exists. Sorry!

Comment: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

Source Error: 


Line 72:   <h2>Video</h2>
Line 73:   <div class="p0">
Line 74:   <object id="obj"  runat="server" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
Line 75:                     codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">
Line 76: <param name="Filename" > now i am facing this error